# Run django and cron in docker-compose

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, cron

I have two similar dockerfiles. They differ only in the `entrypoint`

This is `Dockerfile-cron`

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /src

COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY requirements-dev.txt ./

COPY . ./

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx -y

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements-dev.txt

RUN chmod +x ./cron.sh

CMD ./cron.sh
```

This is `cron.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
* * * * * python manage.py check_subscriptions > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

I have `cron` service in `docker-compose`

```
  cron:
    build: 
      dockerfile: deploy/Dockerfile-cron
      context: .
    networks:
      - sortif-network
```

When I up docker-compose I get error

```
cron_1             | ./cron.sh: line 2: Invoice # 1 (7).pdf: command not found
```

Comment: The command just sets permissions and exits.

Comment: hm. how can run script?..

Comment: Make sure to `COPY` it into the image; don't overwrite it with Compose `volumes:`; and set the image's `CMD` to run the script and not a utility `chmod`.

Comment: @DavidMaze I updated `Dockerfile` and `compose`. When I run `docker-compose up --build cron` I get error `cron_1             | ./cron.sh: line 2: Invoice # 1 (7).pdf: command not found` (`cron.sh` (without `./`) also not work.